# Status bar shifts views down

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I have a view controller in which navigation bar is set to hidden and 
showing my own UIView as navigation bar and have made it transparent. 
I have also set my views frame Y position to 0. so it starts from the Top without any showing any space.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

navBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];

navBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bg.png"]];

[self.view addSubview:navBarView];
```

Above code works when I load this view controller but if I push to any other view controller and comes back to this view controller then status bar takes space and pushes views down.

how to fix it. I have tried every solution known to me.

[image: This is on first load which is perfect]
  [image: This is on back which is thew issue]

Comment: Status or navigation? Can you add before and after pics and show where the core runs (which method)?

Comment: @Wain: I have updated it, hope it is clear now

Comment: Why status bar color is changed?

Comment: @PrafulKadam how did you solve this, I am facing the same issue, can u help

Comment: @Geet : self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; in viewdidload

Comment: Have you solved this problem @PrafulKadam?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something may be wrong with layout constraints. Please try the following code:

```
UIView* navBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];

navBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bg.png"]];

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(navBarView);
NSArray* horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[navBarView]-|"
                                        options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
NSArray* verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[navBarView(64)]-|"
                                                                         options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
NSArray* constraints = [horizontalConstraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:verticalConstraints];
[navBarView addConstraints:constraints];

[self.view addSubview:navBarView];
```

Comment: I noticed that if I use xib subview then only it happens.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the actual code that you use to create the view instead of navigation bar and add it to the superview, and screenshot of your xib?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding your code to viewWillAppear and check if that works ?